# The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string - Cannot connect to MySql Hosts

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple MVC app I'm working on. I'm trying to connect to a MSSQL server using Entity Data Model (code first from database).  After successfully adding the data using the Entity Data Model Wizard, the code below throws the error "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string".  The inner exception is "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySql Hosts.  The thing I can't figure out though, is I'm not using MySql anywhere in the project.  Searching in the project explorer for "MySql" turns up nothing.  Doing a Ctrl+F and searching for MySql also returns nothing found.  My web.config only has the one connection string in it for the MSSQL server connection.  What can I do to figure out why my project is trying to connect to this unknown MySQL server?

My code:

```
string something = kyg.Products.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ItemNo == "128676").ShortDescription.ToString();
```

I don't have an issue with the MSSQL server - I have many apps that are running successfully on the same connection.  I just can't find this unknown reference to a MySql server.  Any Ideas on where to look/what to try?

**Edit** 
I felt it is worth mentioning that I inherited this project, and can't confirm what development was done on it prior to me taking it over.  Also, I was looking through the files, and did find MySql.Data.dll, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll, and MySql.Web.dll.  I moved these files out of the bin folder, and now receive a different error - 
File Not Found - Could not load file or assembly MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll - so something is trying to reference that dll, I just can't figure out what or where it is coming from.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: in your Web.config, check the ConnectionString, check the provider and make sure it's `System.Data.SqlClient`. IF there is no provider, add `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the connection string already has the providerName as "System.Data.SqlClient".

Comment: review the references, code behind files (using), and update the models, Then from the build menu, clean, rebuild the project. See if this would help.

Comment: Are the entities in a separate class library project? I have had issues before were the app.config from the class library was overruling what was in my web.config because the references were in the class library

Comment: entities are in the same project

Comment: alright, I finally found where the mysql reference is coming from. It's included in a referenced .dll file to handle logins. That changes my question a bit - why is the mysql.data in a referenced .dll overriding my mssql entity framework connection, and how can I change it?  Thanks again guys!